# Is There anyway to remove PHPUnit Phar from a OSX machine

Tags: php, eclipse, macos, phpunit, makegood

Hi i have installed PHPUnit using

```
curl https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar -o phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

I am working with PHPUnit , Eclipse and Makegood .

> I have installed another PHPUnit using the composer inside my test
>   folder because i found that Makegood is not working with PHPUnit phar
>   .

Currently i have this error .

```
  [PHPUnit_Framework_Exception]                                                                                           
  Argument #3 (No Value) of PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter::__construct() must be a value from "never", "auto" or "always"  



phpunit [-p|--preload-script="..."] [-c|--config="..."] [-R|--recursive] [-a|--autotest] [-w|--watch-dir="..."] [-m|--notify] [-d|--detailed-progress] [-s|--stop-on-failure] [--log-junit="..."] [--log-junit-realtime] [--test-file-pattern="..."] [--test-method="..."] [--test-class="..."] [--phpunit-config="..."] [test_directory_or_file1] ... [test_directory_or_fileN]
```

One suggestion was to remove the PHPUnit.phar installation .

Is there any command that i can use to delete my old PHPunit installation completely  .
I searched a lot but i could not find any .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Just deleting the file `phpunit.phar` in `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` directory doesn't work?

Comment: hmm tried , but still not working , i am going to restart my computer :D

Comment: @mapek , nope not working  :(

Comment: does `locate phpunit` reports several installations? Is there any error message when you try to delete phpunit?